# HTML Modal Validation with Spring not working because its disappearing

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-thymeleaf

I've created a login and registration for a blog website. However, the problem is that when I log in or register, the website reloads. As a result, my modal disappears, preventing any errors from being displayed. Here is the code:

The Controller:

```java
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String login(Model model, String error, String logout){
        //If loggen in successfully go to /home
        if (securityService.isAuthenticated()) {
            return "redirect:/home";
        }

        //Error Messages (does not work)
        if (error != null)
            model.addAttribute("error", "Your username or password is invalid.");

        if (logout != null) {
            model.addAttribute("logoutMessage", "You have been logged out successfully.");
        }

        return "redirect:/home";
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public String registration(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User userForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        //Validate Input
        userValidator.validate(userForm, bindingResult);

        //If Error (doesnt work)
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("showModal", "true");
            return "index";
        }

        //Save in User Table
        userService.save(userForm);
        //Autologin after Registration
        //securityService.autoLogin(userForm.getUsername(), userForm.getPasswordConfirm());

        return "redirect:/home";
    }
```

my html file:

```html
<!-- Login-Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="loginModalLabel">Anmelden</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="loginForm" method="post" th:action="@{/login}">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="loginUsername">Benutzername</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="loginUsername" name="username" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="loginPassword">Passwort</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="loginPassword" name="password" required>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>

                    <p class="has-error" th:text="${error}" style="color: red"></p>

                    <p th:if="${logoutMessage}" th:text="${logoutMessage}" style="color: green"></p>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                </form>
                <!-- Link zum Registrierungs-Modal -->
                <p class="mt-3 text-center">
                    Noch kein Account?
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#registerModal">Jetzt registrieren!</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- Registrierungs-Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="registerModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="registerModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="registerModalLabel">Registrieren</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form th:action="@{/register}" id="registrationForm" th:object="${userForm}" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="registerUsername">Benutzername</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="registerUsername" th:field="*{username}" required>
                    </div>
                    <p class="has-error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('username')}" th:errors="*{username}" style="color: red"></p>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="registerPassword">Passwort</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="registerPassword" th:field="*{password}" required>
                    </div>
                    <p class="has-error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('password')}" th:errors="*{password}" style="color: red"></p>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="registerPassword">Passwort Wiederholen</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="registerPasswordRepeat" th:field="*{passwordConfirm}" required>
                    </div>
                    <span class="has-error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('passwordConfirm')}" th:errors="*{passwordConfirm}" style="color: red"></span>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Registrieren</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Validation:

```java
    @Override
    public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
        User user = (User) o;

        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "username", "NotEmpty");
        if (user.getUsername().length() < 2 || user.getUsername().length() > 32) {
            errors.rejectValue("username", "Size.userForm.username");
        }
        if (userService.findByUsername(user.getUsername()) != null) {
            errors.rejectValue("username", "Duplicate.userForm.username");
        }

        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "password", "NotEmpty");
        if (user.getPassword().length() < 2 || user.getPassword().length() > 32) {
            errors.rejectValue("password", "Size.userForm.password");
        }

        if (!user.getPasswordConfirm().equals(user.getPassword())) {
            errors.rejectValue("passwordConfirm", "Diff.userForm.passwordConfirm");
        }
    }
}
```

I want the error message to appear below the lines in the modal, something like "too few characters" or similar. This is currently not possible because the page reloads. I've also tried using AJAX, but unfortunately, it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to submit the form via `AJAX` [*asynchronously*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchrony_(computer_programming)).

First, you should include in your project an library to make `AJAX` requests, I'll use [*jQuery*](https://jquery.com/), you can add it in your html file this way:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```

Then, you should modify your HTML form to prevent the default form submission behavior:

```html
<form id="loginForm" method="post" th:action="@{/login}" th:attr="data-url=@{/login}">
```

Also, update your controller to return an JSON responses:

```java
@PostMapping("/login")
public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> login(Model model, String error, String logout) {
    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();

    // If logged in successfully, return a success response
    if (securityService.isAuthenticated()) {
        response.put("success", true);
        return response;
    }

    // Error example
    if (error != null) {
        response.put("success", false);
        response.put("html", "<p style='color: red'>Some error message here!</p>");
    }

    return response;
}
```

**Note:** I suggest you to do it for all your controller methods.

Now, you can handle the form submission by using `AJAX`:

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#loginForm").submit(function (event) {
        // Prevent the default submission
        event.preventDefault();

        var form = $(this);
        var url = form.attr("data-url");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: form.serialize(), // Serialize form data
            success: function (response) {
                // Check the response
                if (response.success) {
                    // Successful login
                    // TODO: Handle
                } else {
                    // Update the modal with the error message
                    $("#loginModal .modal-body").html(response.html);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

It's just an example approach, you can adapt it to your needs.